# Call method multiple times with each member of a collection as parameter

Tags: groovy

Let's say that I have a collection of parameters

```
def params = ['a','b','c']
```

Is there a short way to run a method that accepts a single parameter once for every element of a collection to replace this:

```
params.each {
    foo(it)
}
```

with something more declarative (like a "reverse" spread operator)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
def params = ['a','b','c']

def foo(param) {
    'foo-' + param
}

assert ['foo-a', 'foo-b', 'foo-c'] == params.collect { foo(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just a closure

```
def foo = { a -> a + 2 }
def modified = list.collect foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method pointer:

```
def l = [1,2,3]

l.each(new A().&lol)

class A {
    def lol(l) {
        println l
    }
}
```

Or add a method that will do the task you need:

```
def l = [1,2,3]

List.metaClass.all = { c ->
    delegate.collect(c)
}

l.all(new A().&lol)

class A {
    def lol(l) {
        println l
        return l+2
    }
}
```